# Ошибка PHP при интеграции модуля через composer

Tags: php, api, cdek, sdk2.0

Установил composer, установил в него модуль [CDEK-IT/SDK2.0](https://github.com/cdek-it/sdk2.0/blob/master/docs/index.md) 
После установки в скрипт подтянул autoload.php 
Написал простой скрипт из документации:

```
$client = new Psr18Client();  
$cdek = new \CdekSDK2\Client($client, 'account', 'secure');
    
    try {
        $cdek->authorize();
        $cdek->getToken();
        $cdek->getExpire();
    } catch (AuthException $exception) {
        //Авторизация не выполнена, не верные account и secure
        echo $exception->getMessage();
    }
```

На что в ответ получаю ошибку:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Psr18Client' not found
```

Comment: В ошибке же написано, что аргумент должен быть Psr\\Http\\Client\\ClientInterface, а вы передали null. Скорее всего, $client переменной попросту нет.

Comment: @МаксимНЕпихин обновил ошибку добавив переменную. Как я понял теперь он не видит библиотеку или что...

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `use Symfony\Component\HttpClient\Psr18Client;`, либо попробуйте заменить `new Psr18Client()` на `new Symfony\Component\HttpClient\Psr18Client()`

Answer (score 0):

Подключи либу так

```
composer require symfony/http-client
```

в коде так

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpClient\Psr18Client;
```